# Unable to deploy react-app on heroku- Error status code 503

Tags: heroku, create-react-app

When i tried to deploy react-app on heroku, it sent me following application heroku logs:
It runs locally but not on heroku

```
 State changed from starting to crashed

2020-05-15T11:25:55.816804+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=sakaar.herokuapp.com request_id=08accafa-0117-4e4d-a1b9-8538776d1640 fwd="27.34.50.89" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https

2020-05-15T11:27:58.085863+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=sakaar.herokuapp.com request_id=67f628ce-e6fe-41a5-803b-9f357854f8ba fwd="27.34.50.89" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https

2020-05-15T11:28:03.720923+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=sakaar.herokuapp.com request_id=8774160d-883e-4287-9a5d-1a50bbb22937 fwd="27.34.50.89" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https

2020-05-15T11:28:19.056335+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/postjob" host=sakaar.herokuapp.com request_id=66263e38-de26-4039-8061-90f60f2828bc fwd="27.34.50.89" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Please help me to deploy this react-app on heroku.Let me know if u need anything.

Comment: Did you try with the visual interface on https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps?

Answer (score 0):

This [**article**](https://blog.heroku.com/deploying-react-with-zero-configuration) shows that you only need a few lines **Create and Deploy a React App** in Two Minutes

***You can get started building React apps for free on Heroku.***

```sh
npm install -g create-react-app
create-react-app my-app
cd my-app
git init
heroku create -b https://github.com/mars/create-react-app-buildpack.git
git add .
git commit -m "react-create-app on Heroku"
git push heroku master
heroku open
```